# Next to something in size (phrase meaning) in the sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The two cities which are next to Kuala lampur in size are Tretes and Seleta.

Please explain 'next to something in size' meaning to me.

Comment: Note that "Next to x in size" is not idiomatic: a native speaker would say "the two cities that are next biggest to/after  Kuala Lumpur are Tretes and Seleta"

Answer (score 0):

In that context it would be the next two cities with the largest sizes in sequential order after the first.

Meaning the first city is the largest, the second listed is the second largest, and the third being the final largest comparable city.